# Do I actually need a verified PIN for admob to work on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

I just implemented admob ads in my iOS app.

The admob site says this:

> Your pages are displaying blank ad units because you haven't yet
>   verified your PIN

Indeed, I haven't verified my PIN yet.

However, looking at my app, when I am not in test mode, I ***am*** receiving legit ads.

So, do I need or not the PIN verification? Why am I getting (apparently) legit ads?

Comment: Why don't you just verify the PIN?

Comment: @jcesar: I had it sent now. Meanwhile, I am curious about why am I receiving legit ads in the first place - when I should not.

Answer (score 1):

ADMOB technically doesn't work on any device without a validated pin because you won't get paid.

It doesn't cost anything to get a pin but the wait can be compared to waiting on a shipment of LED's and bezels from Szechuan China which takes about a month.

[Click here to get an ADMOB PIN](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3198657?hl=en)

Comment: I requested one already. But question is, why am I getting legit ads?

Comment: Probably you get legit ads because the man (google) wants you to know admob is working correctly.

Comment: That might be it. But why is my account balance increasing when my users tap such ads?

Comment: I'm guessing that money would be held until such time that your account is verified.  Note I'm currently waiting on two 3 digit voltage displays from Szechuan.  It's taking forever similar to length of time it took me to reply to this comment.  I've been busy with mid terms.